# Getting error while deploying SSRS report via GITHUB desktop

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, jenkins, reporting-services

I am facing one error while deploying one SSRS report via GitHub desktop. The same code is working fine in running in VS, but when I am trying to commit the same from GIT, I am getting below deploy error in Jenkins. Please help me out.
[image]